# Using Synchonized in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am seeing this behavior in my Springboot application. So, I have a component in my application as:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
   public methodA() {
      synchronized(this) {
           // some operation
      }  
   }

   public methodB() {
      synchronized(this) {
           // some operation
      }  
   }
    
   public methodC() {
      synchronized(this) {
           // some operation
      }  
   }
}
```

When I am running multiple threads calling the methods, there is slowness seen which is because of the locking, which is as expected.

Now for the same class, if intstead of using `synchronized(this)`, if I use a different object created as member variable in the class, I don't see the slowness anymore.

```
@Service
public class MyService {
   Object obj;
   
   @PostConstruct
   void init() {
      this.obj = new Object();
   }
   
   public methodA() {
      synchronized(obj) {
           // some operation
      }  
   }

   public methodB() {
      synchronized(obj) {
           // some operation
      }  
   }

   public methodC() {
      synchronized(obj) {
           // some operation
      }  
   }
}
```

I am having hard time in understanding this behaviour, since in both cases object monitor is used, only that objects are different. Does it have anything to do with Springboot bean used as the monitor?

Comment: Could you add the code that demonstrates that one is faster that the other? I fail to imagine why there could possibly be a difference.

Answer (score -1):

In the first example, it means that the lock is acquired on the instance of the class itself (eg `this` refers to current instance). This creates a single  lock for all the synchronized blocks in the class. Multiple threads are trying to execute your methods at the same time, so they will fight for the same lock. This can cause delays as each thread is waiting for the lock to be released.

In the second scenario you give, you create a separate `Object` instance (`obj`) and each method now synchronises on its own `obj` instance resulting in each method having its own lock. This leads to better performance as you mention because the threads are acquiring different locks rather than the same one.

Comment: There are exactly as many MyService as there are MyService.obj.

Comment: @Sören is right. The only advantage of using a private object to lock on is that external code cannot "steal" your lock by using `synchronized (beanInstance)`. However, Spring Boot's proxy mechanism probably already prevents that.